# Textfield did end editing crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield

I've set up an exception breakpoint and was getting the error `unrecognized selector sent to instance` the instance was the UITableViewCell itself. The app uses CoreData and when the UITextfield ends editing I want to save the text to the NSManagedObject.

Here's the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method within my TableViewController:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell = (MCSwipeTableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;
    TehdaItem *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]];


    item.itemTitle = cell.itemLabel.text; //The exception gets thrown on this line
// itemLabel is a UITextField and itemTitle is a string attribute of TehdaItem the NSManagedObject

    NSError *error;
    [item.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

}
```

The `<UITextFieldDelegate>` is set as my TableViewController and I've set it as the delegate for the UITextField. Can't really figure out what the problem here is.

EDIT: Removing the the last `superview` call in `MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell = (MCSwipeTableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;` has solved the problem.

Comment: Please show us the full error message and tell us the line in which it was thrown. There is the name of the method/selector in question within that message.

Comment: Sorry, you did mark the line. There is a problem if it was really an UITableViewCell because it should have been a MCSwipeTableViewCell. UITableViewCell cannot respond to itemLabel. Again, please show the full error message.

Comment: Here is the error message `-[UITableView itemLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8828c00` the instance being `cell = (MCSwipeTableViewCell`.

Comment: Sorry about the title, I fixed it. I actually wasn't getting an error message until I removed a symbolic break point. So I couldn't give the exact one until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently the superview of the superview of your UITextField is of the type UITableViewCell and not the MCSwipeTableViewCell object that you expect. Have a look at where the cell is created, which is most probably cellForRowAtIndexPath and/or it is the class assignment for the prototype cell that you did in inteface builder/storyboard editor.

Comment: So I've checked my storyboard and I had set the class to MCSwipeTableViewCell earlier. Checking the cellForRowAtIndexPath also didn't really help since All my pointers use MCSwipeTableViewCell rather than UITableViewCell.

Comment: Editing `MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell = (MCSwipeTableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;` and taking out the last `superview` call ended up solving the issue. I wouldn't have even thought to look there without your suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, now that I see the error message it even gets clear that there was one superview to much. How could we know? You could have had a regular view between the text view and the cell. - However, you are welcome. Glad to help.